# Call method inside Workflow's IF ChartFlow

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I am using `Windows Workflow Foundation 4`and as part of more complicated scenario I have those two states:

[image: States]

The idea is that the users are allowed to upload files which is part of the whole workflow. There may be several reason which my lead to the fact that an uploaded file can not be processed immediately. One of the reasons may be that currently there is a file uploaded from a certain user which is being processed so every other file uploaded during the processing should be in state `WaitingProcessing`. However when I enter the `WaitingProcessing` state I need to check this. In order to do that I have to implement something like this:

[image: Detailed state]

where generally the `HasFileToProcess` is a function which will call a stored procedure from the database to check if currently there is a file for this user which is in state `Processing`.

Almost all parts of the tasks are clear, one thing that I don't know how to do is how to call e function inside the condition field. In fact I have almost zero experience with `Windows Workflow` at all so I'm not even sure that this is the way to go so as a sub-question I would appreciate if someone knows and show me if there is better way to implement this kind of logic.

Comment: You might want to take a look at native activity [InvokeMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.statements.invokemethod(v=vs.110).aspx). It allows one to call a method and get its returned value either on a static class or specifying a target object.

Comment: You can certainly go for @Jota's example which would work. However I would feel a cleaner solution would be to roll your own custom activity to achieve your goal. If required I can provide a basic example.

Comment: @Leron how eventually you solved the problem?

Comment: @danieltheman Hi there. Sorry but I won't be able to give you a straight up answer. In short - this post was result of my (ex) company wanting to transition to newer version of `WWF` but it turned out that there are a lot of changes in `4.x` so we just decided to stick to the oldest `3.x` version. Also I would advice you to stop using the interface and go straight to the `XML` file. At first it seems harder but after some time it actually makes some things easier. When you do that, it's easier to insert snippets calling custom `Activites` which is actually your end goal.  ..

Comment: In `WWF` 3.x it is easy just to open the XML and insert a line calling some activity which is basically a class with whatever functionality you want to be there and you are done. I'm pretty sure that you can do something similar in the newer version but the matter of fact is - we decided not to put the effort into figuring it out. So.. yeah, if you feel stuck, just check how this is done 3.x version and then ask more specific question how to do the same thing in 4.x version. Sorry I can't be of more help to you.

Comment: @Leron thanks anyway!